# installing intellij with failing to initialize graphics environment

Tags: intellij-idea

I am installing intellij in the development machine, linux system, but when i run the bin/idea.sh, then installing program shows

> "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Failed to
>   initialize graphics environment"

what's wrong with it

Comment: Can you run any other GUI apps on this system?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you are running the idea.sh as root. Try running it again as a user it will start.

Comment: I want to be able to run IDEA, Pycharm, etc. using different users. So this answer is not providing any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @harivicky mentioned, you're probably trying to run the app using not your `main_user`, but `root` or something else. Just run:

   - `sudo su main_user`
   - `./idea.sh`

---

2. Also, you may want to be able to run IDEA for different users like:
   `main_user`, `root`, `dummy_user1`, `dummy_user2`, etc.

   In this case, you must provide access to a display as the `main_user`:

   - `sudo su main_user` - switch to the `main_user`
   - `xhost +` - add access for a display to all users
   - `sudo su root` - switch to the `root`
   - `./idea.sh` - as you see now you can run apps using different users

[1, 2] - work for Ubuntu 17.10

*Update:*
The next day I couldn't run `./idea` because some errors appeared. So I did this:

- added `export DISPLAY=:1` to the `/etc/environment` file
- sudo su `main_user`
- sudo su `root` (this login switch is required in order to apply changes in `/etc/environment` )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run as root, then you can do this(below is for clion but should work for intellij as well) -

This error occurs because the default configuration of the X server permissions does not allow the root to connect to it.
To verify this, we used xhost X server access control program to check the permissions.
Executing xhost with no command line arguments gave us a message indicating whether or not access control was currently enabled, followed by the list of those users allowed to connect.
For example in our case the output was as follows:

```
[george@bytefreaks bin]$ xhost
```

access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:george
To add root to the list of users that was allowed to start an X application we executed the following command:

```
[george@bytefreaks bin]$ xhost +si:localuser:root
localuser:root being added to access control list
```

Executing xhost again, we got the updated list which included the root

```
[george@bytefreaks bin]$ xhost
```

access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:root
SI:localuser:george
After this, we were able to start CLion using sudo with no problems.

```
[george@bytefreaks bin]$ sudo ./clion.sh
```

Note: This patch is not permanent, we actually execute it once at every restart of the machine.

Source  - https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/start-clion-as-root-on-fedora